# Insert a new field in a specific admin view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, satchmo

I'm trying to extend default Django's model with a new field. 
In localsite/models.py I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from satchmo_store.contact.models import Organization

class OrganizationExtra(models.Model):
    organization = models.OneToOneField(Organization,
            verbose_name=_('Organization'), primary_key=True )
    vat_number   = models.CharField(_('VAT'), max_length=12)
```

Followed with run of `./manage.py syncdb` which did created a new table for above model. So far so good.

Now I'm trying to add this new field in related `Organization` view in the *admin interface*.
The following code registers the new menu, however the new `vat_number` field is not displayed in view of the related `Organization` model.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from localsite.models import ProductResource, OrganizationExtra

admin.site.register(OrganizationExtra)
```

The original `Organization` model is registered with

```
from satchmo_store.contact.models import Organization
from django.contrib import admin

class OrganizationOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['type', 'role']
    list_display = ['name', 'type', 'role']

admin.site.register(Organization, OrganizationOptions)
```

Any idea how to insert my new field without touching original Satchmo sources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/custom-admin.html) as usual.

One possible way is to create new `MyOrganization` derived from `Organization` and register it in place of satchmo one

Your `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from satchmo_store.contact.models import Organization

class MyOrganization(Organization):
    vat_number   = models.CharField(_('VAT'), max_length=12)
```

Your `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from localsite.models import MyOrganization
from satchmo_store.contact.models import Organization
from satchmo_store.contact.admin import OrganizationOptions

admin.site.unregister(Organization)
admin.site.register(MyOrganization, OrganizationOptions)
```

Another possible solution (if you wish to stick with `OrganizationExtra`) is to create custom form for `Organization` for admin interface and again reregister model. By it seems to me as more boilerplate and result will be the same.

**NB:** in both cases DB structure would be the same, i.e. extra table would be created.

Comment: Ah, shame on me. I've completely missed this section in docs.